How do I store a chunks page-origin with the Azure textSplitter skillset?
I have a text splitter skill applied to my Azure AI search in order to split my PDFs into chunks (one page at a time).
When the data is properly chunked and indexed however, it is impossible to identify the page of origin. How can I save the page of origin to a metadata key, or otherwise fetch the page number after or during search?
This is the main part of my splitting skillset:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://documentsearch.search.windows.net/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\",
  "name": "vector-skillset",
  "description": "Skillset to chunk documents and generate embeddings",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill",
      "name": "#1",
      "description": null,
      "context": "/document/pages/*",
      "resourceUri": "https://app.openai.azure.com",
      "apiKey": "<redacted>",
      "deploymentId": "embedder",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/pages/*"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "embedding",
          "targetName": "vector"
        }
      ],
      "authIdentity": null
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
      "name": "#2",
      "description": "Split skill to chunk documents",
      "context": "/document",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "textSplitMode": "pages",
      "maximumPageLength": 2000,
      "pageOverlapLength": 500,
      "maximumPagesToTake": 0,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/content"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "textItems",
          "targetName": "pages"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": null,
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": {
    "selectors": [
      {
        "targetIndexName": "vector",
        "parentKeyFieldName": "parent_id",
        "sourceContext": "/document/pages/*",
        "mappings": [
          {
            "name": "chunk",


You can generate the page number by setting the imageAction to generateNormalizedImagePerPage in the indexer parameters configuration, which only applies to PDF files. Otherwise, use generateNormalizedImages.
Below is the definition of how you set the imageAction.
{
  "parameters":
  {
    "configuration": 
    {
       "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
       "parsingMode": "default",
       "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImagePerPage"
    }
  }
}

And it gives you the results with the following members in the /document/normalized_images/* or /document/normalized_images/*/pages context.
  {
    "data": "BASE64 ENCODED STRING OF A JPEG IMAGE",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 300,
    "originalWidth": 5000,  
    "originalHeight": 3000,
    "rotationFromOriginal": 90,
    "contentOffset": 500,
    "pageNumber": 2
  }

Refer to this page for more information.
Next, pass this column to your custom web API skillset where you return the page number and any other required output.
Either you pass whole values in inputs of the skillset by giving /document/normalized_images/*  or only /document/normalized_images/*/pageNumber.
Sample skillset definition.
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
  "uri": "Your_web_api_url",
  "httpHeaders": "",
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "timeout": "PT30S",
  "batchSize": 0,
  "degreeOfParallelism": 0,
  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "context": "/document/normalized_images/*",
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "normalized_images",
      "source": "/document/normalized_images/*"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "pageNumber",
      "targetName": "pageNumber"
    }
  ]
}

Here, your web application should return the page number extracted from inputs /document/normalized_images/*.
To learn more about custom web API skills, refer to this page.
